# Detect when measure pass of a fragment's main view is finished (or Android equivalent of viewDidLayoutSubviews)

Tags: android, ios, android-fragments

I have a class that is subclassing the main Android `Fragment` class. This `ViewFragment` is then being subclassed by a bunch of other classes that display various things.

I have a method in that class that I want to run when the 'measure' pass on the main view returned by the fragment's `OnCreateView()` method is finished (the reason being, I want to detect the measured height of the view and if it's longer than the screen, add an extra view at the bottom). In particular, I want to be able to call the `invalidate()` method of the fragment's main view and then detect when the measurement is finished.

Because different types of views are being returned by the `onCreateView()` of the different subclasses, I can't simply override methods on the returned view.

Now this is actually a port from iOS, where Fragment = UIViewController. In iOS land, the result I'm after is achieved by overriding the `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an abstract method View getView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState), call it in your onCreateView and add returned View to custom FrameLayout which overrides onMeasure() and finally return that custom FrameLayout

Comment: I can see how this could work. Seems like an awful lot of effort though. Anyway, I'll try it and see how it goes.